# How to deal with Error: Exception message

Tags: javascript, oop

Can u help me resolve a problem ?
I am trying solve a case in codewars. https://www.codewars.com/kata/51fda2d95d6efda45e00004e/train/javascript

And this is my code:

```
function User() {
const rankArr = [-8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
this.rank = -8;
this.progress = 0;
this.incProgress = function (incProgress) {
    if (this.rank >= 8 || incProgress == 0 || incProgress > 8 || incProgress < -8 || !incProgress) {
        this.progress = 0;
        throw new Error("Exception message");
    } else {
        const index = rankArr.indexOf(this.rank);
        const length = rankArr.indexOf(incProgress) - index;
        if (length <= -2) {
            length = -2;
        }
        let point;
        switch (length) {
            case 0:
                point = 3;
                break;
            case -1:
                point = 1;
                break;
            case -2:
                point = 0;
                break;
            default:
                point = Math.pow(length, 2) * 10;
        }
        this.progress += point;
        if (this.progress >= 100) {
            const levelUp = Math.floor(this.progress / 100);
            this.rank = rankArr[index + levelUp];
            this.progress -= levelUp * 100;
        }
        if (this.rank == 8) {
            this.progress = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

}

Every is fine but i got a Error in Test case even if I pass all test case

> Error: Exception message
> at User.incProgress
> at assert
> at /home/codewarrior/index.js:113:5
> at begin
> at it
> at /home/codewarrior/index.js:75:3
> at /runner/frameworks/javascript/cw-2.js:152:11
> at Promise._execute
> at Promise._resolveFromExecutor
> at new Promise
> at describe
> at /home/codewarrior/index.js:74:1
> at /home/codewarrior/index.js:122:5
> at Object.handleError

Can u turn out for me that problem ?

Comment: The if at the beginning.?

Comment: Can you mark `index.js:113` line?

Comment: Omg, that is wrong in this.rank >= 8 , thanks u so much.